# Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) - Add button isn't working anymore

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am following the [*Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) by Apple, at the paragrapher *Implement Edit and Delete Behavoir*. After I implemented edit and delete behaviors, I noticed that the **Add (+)** button isn't working anymore. Here is the code that gives me an error when trying the Add button:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

    case "AddItem":
        os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

    case "ShowDetail":
        guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }

        guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
        }

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }

        let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
        mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
    }
}
```

[Here is the warning and the suggested Fix-its](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T68JT.png)

[Here is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4JHy.png)

[Here is the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41O9d.png)

[Here is the segue identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F5CX.png)

[Here is the identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDCoE.png)

Here are the files provided by Apple, which by the way are the same I am using:
https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/08_ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.zip

I know that this code is old and needs to be upgraded to Swift 4.1, but I don't have much experience so I can't do it myself. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: check the storyboard and make sure there is a segue from the add button and make sure from the segue identifier

Comment: @user3601599 I edited the post and added the storyboard and the segue identifier.

Comment: Please post the error you mentioned you get when trying to add the button. All you've shown are warnings that can be fixed like this `"... \(someOptionalString ?? "")"`

Comment: @regina_fallangi Done.

Comment: It’s telling you that identifier does not exist. Can you show that you have set the correct identifier in the interface builder?

Comment: @regina_fallangi Done. You were right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error, you're reaching the default case when you switch on the segue identifier. That means that the identifier in the segue doesn't match any of the cases. And indeed, the message says that the identifier is `addItem`, which doesn't match `AddItem` or `ShowDetail`. Looks like segue identifiers are case sensitive, huh? So change the segue identifier in your storyboard to match one of the ones you expect, probably `AddItem`, and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have miswrote the Identifier. Less serious than I thought!

Comment: Glad to help. It can be hard to notice small differences like capitalization or white space.